# Using Variables to Refernce Start and End of Range

Tags: excel, range

I am trying to figure out how to use variables to reference the start and end of a range where the start and finish could be any range in a column. I am getting input from the user that defines the starting row and ending row and storing them as variables. I just cant seem to find anywhere that is giving me the right syntax for what I am trying to do.  Below is what I tried from another post and gives me an error "Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed"

```
Dim Start As Integer
Dim End As Integer
Dim rng As Range

Start=Cells(1,1).Value
End=Cells(1,2).Value

rng = Range("B" & Start &": B" & End &"")
```

Ultimately I am trying to get the range and find the average of that range and store it as a variable but I just cant seem to find the right syntax for my sheet anywhere.  Any help is much appreciated!!!!

Comment: I just figured it out using a different method for anyone interested.  Used the following:  Set rng = Range(Cells(Start,2),Cells(End,2))

Comment: Worth making sure you fully qualify each range reference to - `Thisworkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").range(Thisworkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").cells(start,2), Thisworkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").cells(end,2))` - hopefully fairly obvious that `Thisworkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")` would be stored in a Worksheet variable type.